# Maui ListView binding to items of a list

Tags: c#, .net, maui

I am having some issues binding labels in a `ListView` to properties of items in a list in my ViewModel.

The ItemsSource of the ListView binds to the list just fine, but I can not access the properites of items in that list. Can anyone see what I am missing?

Compiler Message:

```
XFC0045 Binding: Property "Name" not found on "SocketApp.Pages.ConnectionPageViewModel".
```

XAML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="SocketApp.Pages.ConnectionsPage"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SocketApp.Pages"
             x:DataType="local:ConnectionPageViewModel"> <!-- ViewModel Set -->
    <StackLayout >
        <!-- Binding the List to the ListView -->
        <!-- This works fine -->
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ListItems}" HasUnevenRows="True" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" >
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell >
                        <Grid Padding="5"  HeightRequest="50">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="9*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5" >
                                <!-- Try to Bind to a property of an item within the list  -->
                                <!-- This is what is not working  -->
                                <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Name}" FontAttributes="Bold" />
                                <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Address}" FontAttributes="Italic" VerticalOptions="End" />
                            </StackLayout>
                        </Grid>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

ViewModel:

```
public class ConnectionPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private List<ConnectionListItem> _listItems = new List<ConnectionListItem>();
    public List<ConnectionListItem> ListItems
    {
        get => _listItems;
        set
        {
            _listItems = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ListItems));
        }
    }
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Comment: get rid of `x:DataType`, or add the correct one to `DataTemplate`

Comment: Is your class "SocketApp.Pages.ConnectionsPage" or is it "SocketApp.Pages.ConnectionPage" because everywhere else it is named without the s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `x:DataType` tag will automatically be applied to all child controls. So if you want to use that, you will have to apply a `x:DataType` attribute to your `ViewCell` or any of the lower children so that the bindings in there will know they now need to look at another object.

Another solution is to remove the `x:DataType` altogether, but then you will lose the functionality as a whole.

This is known as [compiled bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/data-binding/compiled-bindings).